# invalid \escape line when using json.loads()

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, api

I am trying to convert a string to json format.
However, i bumped into an error - invalid /escape line

```
a = "[{"data":"APPLE FUJI\O7P","group":"fruits","price":"3.0"},{"data":"ORANGE","group":"fruits","price":"2.0"}]"

json_a = json.loads(a, strict=False)
```

"APPLE FUJI\O7P" is a valid data, just using fruits as an example.

I am unable to add in additional backslash or to replace backslash with another character due to data validation issue.

Any alternative solution on how i can convert the string to a json format by ignoring the "".
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: json.loads() require str type object and you are passing a list. Show your input and expected output.

Comment: hi @Hamzausmanghani, updated the qn. a is supposed to be a string. added the double quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use single quotes to define `a`, will this work for you? Using `eval`...

```
a = '[{"data":"APPLE FUJI\O7P","group":"fruits","price":"3.0"},{"data":"ORANGE","group":"fruits","price":"2.0"}]'
newa = eval(a)
j = json.loads(json.dumps(newa))
for itm in j:
    # print(itm)
    print(itm['data'])
    print(itm['group'])
    print(itm['price'])
```

Output

```
APPLE FUJI\O7P
fruits
3.0
ORANGE
fruits
2.0
```